# how to make array of words contained in string?

Tags: iphone

i have a string

`gpbusd buy    update HIT 40 PIPS HIT 110 PIPS  gpbusd buy   BREAK EVEN update HIT 100+  gpbusd buy 1.5500/25 1.5455  new 40 100+  gpbusd buy    update CLOSE 0 TO 10 PIPS N   gpbusd buy 1.5335/50 1.5320  new 40 80+  gpbusd buy    update  15-20 PIPS CLOSE KEEP OPEN gpbusd buy 1.5530/50  1.5505 update HIT 80 KEEP OPEN gpbusd buy 1.5530/50 1.5465  new 40 80 100+ gbpjpy sell 131.05/.130.75 132.15  new 60 100 keep open eurusd sell 1.2840/20 1.2870 STOP update`

i want to make array of the words contained between spaces of string?how can i do it?

Comment: You already got answer for that in your previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767721/how-to-remove-a-particular-sign-from-a-string. just reread an answer carefully...

Comment: yes , array of anything between spaces for iphone sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with

`NSArray *words = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];`

[More here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer you  are looking for...this will check multiple spaces also

replace str with your string(i am using str as an example)

NSMutableArray *arr;

```
NSString *str=@"mango        apple    banana grapes    pineapple";
NSRange match;  

arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


while(str.length>0)
{
match = [str rangeOfString: @" "];
    if(match.location>=str.length)
    {
        [arr addObject:str];
        break;
    }
NSString *str2=[str substringToIndex:match.location];
str=[str substringFromIndex:match.location+1];
    if(str2.length==0)
    {
        continue;   
    }
[arr addObject:str2];
}
NSLog(@"array is %@",arr);    //here is your array
```

this is working fine in my app. hope it will also help you